# The execution sequence after conditional variable notify

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-mutex

There are two threads (Call them T1 and T2) that sync with each other by boost condition variable and mutex like:

```
boost::condition_variable global_cond;
boost::mutex global_mutex;
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock( global_mutex);

thread1() {
  global_cond.notify_one();
  code_block_a();
}

tread2() {
  global_cond.wait(lock)
  code_block_b();
}
```

Let's say I can gugarntee that thread2 come to wait first and then thread1 will do the notify.

My question is, is that determinastic that code_block_a() or code_block_b() will execute first?

Comment: Generally? No. In your code? Who knows. Maybe if you posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Not guaranteed. The system may perform context switching right after `thread1` called `notify_one()` and allow thread2() to run. And it may not.

Please note that your code is generally buggy because `global_cond.wait(lock)` can be spuriously woken up and `tread2` can run `code_block_b()` even before `thread1()` has run.